# 24 minutes to 1 day

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I need help if this is possible. So, we know 20 minutes is 1 day in Minecraft so, my question is, is there any way I can slow down the time to make it 24 minutes is 1 day in Minecraft or even slower? I'm doing this on MCPE, btw

Comment: why would you want to do that, do you have a specific need that could be achieved otherwise?

Comment: @Chund I think OP would like to have something easy to count hours (1 real minute for 1 hour, 1 real second for 1 minute), it could be really useful if he wants to reproduce a clock (on a church for example)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there are only options to freeze or to set time in any version of the game, you could however set a redstone clock, that every once in awhile freezes time for some time, something like freezing for 1 minute, every 5 minutes, which would grant you your wanted result.

If such a clock is running in the spawn chunks your problem should be solved (at least that is how i would try to address it in Java. Don't know if that is applicable in pocket-edition, since redstone is not really reliable in that edition as I heard).

Comment: Isn't a normal day 20 minutes?
so i freeze after 5 min for 1 min => one loop ends after 6 minutes real time and 5 min ingame time

Comment: yeah, sorry, I didn't see it like that